# When to make Spring instantiate a bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When should you let Spring instantiate a bean? and when should you instantiate a bean yourself via Java?

For example: I have a Contact class which I will use as a form backing object.
My bean:

```
public class Contact()
{
   private String name;
   ...
}
```

Should I let Spring handle this?

Please give a detailed explanation and example. Thanks.

Comment: 1. always, except when unit-testing the bean. 2. Never, except when unit-testing the bean. (I assume that by "bean", you mean "spring bean").

Comment: As I know, a bean is considered a Spring bean when you let Spring manage it. Therefore, I'm pertaining to all types of beans. So do you mean, I should let Spring instantiate all beans?

Comment: So, do you in fact mean "Object" when you say "bean"? If so, no, of course all objects must not be instantiated by Spring. Spring should typically be used to instantiate controllers, services and DAOs. You can go further of course, and use Spring wherever you feel dependency injection adds value. Your question is a bit vague. Please add a concrete example where you ask yourself such a question.

Comment: If you say Object, you are pertaining to all like ArrayList() etc. That is not what I meant. I edited my question, sorry for that.

Comment: If it's a form-backing object and you're using Spring MVC, then read Spring MVC's docmentation to know how to handle form submissions. They're typically instantiated by Spring, or by a ModelAttribute-annotated method.

Comment: Look at the net.viralpatel.spring3.controller.ContactController of this site: [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/). As you can see in his showContacts() method, he instantiates the Contact class instead of Spring instantiating it, that's why I'm confuse when to instantiate and when to not instantiate a bean.

Comment: Why don't you ask that precise question from the beginning? The badly names `showContacts()` is used to display the contact creation form. This form gets the value of its input fields from a blank contact (but this blank contact could be pre-populated with some initial values). So the blank contact is created and stored in the model by the controller. What matters here is not who creates this contact (it could also be created by Spring), but where the form gets its initial values from.

Comment: Just to clear things up, so in cases like this, should I let Spring instantiate the Contact bean? Why?

Comment: No, there's no good reason to let Spring instantiate the bean. Don't think in terms of "what do I have to do?". Think in terms of "what do I want to do? How to use Spring to do that?". If you want to put a blank contact in the model, use the way you find the most appropriate to have this blank contact instantiated and put in the model.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I really appreciated it and sorry for being vague at the beginning. I think this quote of yours answers this question "Spring should typically be used to instantiate controllers, services and DAOs. You can go further of course, and use Spring wherever you feel dependency injection adds value."

Comment: In the case of Spring MVC (which wasn't mentioned in the original question), form-backing objects must also be instantiated, populated from the request parameters, and validated by Spring. In this, specific case you finally asked about, Spring just needs an object in the model, and instantiating yourself is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes that provide services such as DAOs and Services (EmployeeDAO, EmployeeService) and its dependencies such as DataSources, etc. should be instantiated by Spring.  Value objects such as Employee object itself should be instantiated by your code.